# Silencers not available due to missing resource

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I am using a silenced tranq sniper rifle (because why would you not?) and of course, the silencer runs out after a time.  So, I called a supply drop but was told that "some items are not available because of a lack of resources".  I look at the iDroid and could not find anything low or just empty.

I looked at the official guide but could not find anything about that.

As a work around, I can switch the silencer from the machine gun. But I would like to know what I am missing so I can get some more of that.

Any one encountered this and can enlighten me?

Comment: Did the ammo refill at the time?

Comment: @Jeeva: Yes, all the tranq ammo refreshed fine for both the pistol and sniper rifle.  The only thing that was missing (as far as I could tell, the message did not specify *which* things would be missing or *why*) was a new silencer for the rifle.

Comment: The only thing I can think of tranquilizer rifles specifically needing are a plant. I cannot remember which one exactly, but maybe if you don't have it they wont give you a new suppressor?

Comment: @DangerZone: I looked at my iDroid and all my plants have something in the high 100s. None of them are greyed out.

Comment: As i recall from Peace Walker, i sometimes had issues with higher grade versions of weapons being out of stock when equipping for an Op. Could be same problem

Comment: By chance was this gun customized? By this I mean was the silencer not native to that model? I had the same issue once and this was why.

Comment: @Dupree3: It could well have been. Care to expend on your comment in an answer?

Comment: Note that sometimes items can require specific resources like the medicinal plants, not just the usual resources. My bet is something like that happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same thing happen to me once, this was on a gun that I had customized and added a silencer that was a grade above what I already had developed for that specific gun. To be a little bit more specific I added a level 2 silencer to my sniper rifle before I had one developed for that model. I took it from the assault rifle I had made. When I went to deploy a supply drop to myself for the first time with that it said the exact thing you noted. It only happened once as I made the upgrade to give me a level 2 silencer shortly after. It could have been the combination of the assault rifle suppressor on the sniper....or maybe I was in the process of developing the sniper with the level 2 suppressor at the time... I did not look in to it much since it worked fine the following attempt maybe a day later worth of game time. Hope this helps you.

Comment: This pretty much describes my "issue". Thanks.

Comment: @Sardathrion Glad I could help!